# tf for mutiple Aruco markers

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm able to get the tf for one Aruco marker .Here is my code snippet

```
br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
   
   
br.sendTransform((msg.pose.position.x,msg.pose.position.y,msg.pose.position.z),
                     (msg.pose.orientation.x,msg.pose.orientation.y,msg.pose.orientation.z,msg.pose.orientation.w),
                     rospy.Time.now(),
                     msg.child_frame_id,
                     "/camera_link")
```

So, if i have multiple markers how to add frames for each of the detected marker`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308881/tf-for-mutiple-aruco-markers/) by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it by adding an array type message then subscribing to it. No more hard-coding required.

---

Originally posted by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) with karma: 85 on 2018-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [odd-incubus](https://answers.ros.org/users/85378/odd-incubus/) on 2022-01-27**:
can you explain this in a bit more detail? thanks!